# jquery - get number of li inside a ul element

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists

I need to get number of `li` element inside a `ul`. in fact i want to perform specific action when a `ul` has no child. is there any way to do that with jquery?

Comment: Yes there is.  What have you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.has()` selector:

```
if(!$('ul').has('li')){//ul is empty

}
```

Comment: aww snap...typo...thanks.

Comment: Because it is a poor answer and a duplicate.

Comment: @PWKad: i understand. but should not the question be downvoted rather than answer.

Comment: I downvoted them all.  It's a poor question that is a duplicate and a poor answerer who chooses to give a half-way answer rather than flag a duplicate.